# How can I correctly export and import my .svg library that holds icons for UI and logos for companies? Is my tsconfig setup properly?

Tags: typescript, npm, svg, tsconfig, npm-package

**Overview:**

I have a library of `svg` icons that I want to publish and I'm having either problems with the `typescript` types (There aren't any to export). I'm not entirely sure if I am exporting the `.svg` file since I'm just importing each file into `index.ts` such as:

```js
export const chromeIcon = './svgs/browser/chromeIcon.svg';
```

**Example `.svg`**

```js
<svg width="256px" height="257px" viewBox="0 0 256 257" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="49.9976632%" y1="0.70578635%" x2="49.9976632%" y2="96.9898739%" id="linearGradient-1">
      <stop stop-color="#86BBE5" offset="0%"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="#1072BA" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <path d="M127.788721,0.035213205 C127.788721,0.035213205 203.109766,-3.34525447 243.041541,72.3631362 L121.379917,72.3631362 C121.379917,72.3631362 98.4209078,71.6236589 78.8071527,99.477304 C73.1730399,111.168088 67.1163686,123.211004 73.9125172,146.944704 C64.1232462,130.359285 21.9378267,56.9045392 21.9378267,56.9045392 C21.9378267,56.9045392 51.6929849,3.02833563 127.788721,0.035213205 L127.788721,0.035213205 Z" fill="#EF3F36"></path>
    <path d="M239.132875,192.228886 C239.132875,192.228886 204.377442,259.169188 118.87978,255.859147 C129.443741,237.583494 179.728198,150.501238 179.728198,150.501238 C179.728198,150.501238 191.876754,130.993122 177.544979,100.075928 C170.255846,89.335901 162.82586,78.1028886 138.88088,72.1166437 C158.142503,71.9405777 242.830261,72.1166437 242.830261,72.1166437 C242.830261,72.1166437 274.557359,124.830812 239.132875,192.228886 L239.132875,192.228886 Z" fill="#FCD900"></path>
    <path d="M16.9727648,192.757084 C16.9727648,192.757084 -23.6280605,129.197249 22.0082531,56.7988996 C32.5370014,75.074553 82.821458,162.156809 82.821458,162.156809 C82.821458,162.156809 93.6671252,182.439615 127.577442,185.46795 C140.500688,184.517194 153.952132,183.70729 171.136176,165.995048 C161.663824,182.756534 119.161486,256 119.161486,256 C119.161486,256 57.6088033,257.126823 16.9727648,192.757084 L16.9727648,192.757084 Z" fill="#61BC5B"></path>
    <path d="M118.844567,256.492985 L135.958184,185.080605 C135.958184,185.080605 154.762036,183.601651 170.537552,166.311967 C160.748281,183.531224 118.844567,256.492985 118.844567,256.492985 L118.844567,256.492985 Z" fill="#5AB055"></path>
    <path d="M70.4616231,129.056396 C70.4616231,97.5757909 95.9911967,72.0462173 127.471802,72.0462173 C158.952407,72.0462173 184.481981,97.5757909 184.481981,129.056396 C184.481981,160.537001 158.952407,186.066575 127.471802,186.066575 C95.9911967,186.031362 70.4616231,160.537001 70.4616231,129.056396 L70.4616231,129.056396 Z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
    <path d="M80.0044017,129.056396 C80.0044017,102.857772 101.237964,81.5889959 127.471802,81.5889959 C153.670426,81.5889959 174.939202,102.822558 174.939202,129.056396 C174.939202,155.255021 153.70564,176.523796 127.471802,176.523796 C101.273177,176.523796 80.0044017,155.255021 80.0044017,129.056396 L80.0044017,129.056396 Z" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"></path>
    <path d="M242.795048,72.1518569 L172.333425,92.8220083 C172.333425,92.8220083 161.699037,77.2225585 138.845667,72.1518569 C158.670702,72.0462173 242.795048,72.1518569 242.795048,72.1518569 L242.795048,72.1518569 Z" fill="#EACA05"></path>
    <path d="M72.5392022,144.338927 C62.6442916,127.190096 21.9378267,56.9045392 21.9378267,56.9045392 L74.1237964,108.527098 C74.1237964,108.527098 68.7713893,119.548831 70.778542,135.324347 L72.5392022,144.338927 L72.5392022,144.338927 Z" fill="#DF3A32"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Error:**

```js
TS2307: Cannot find module '@jeff/svgs' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

**Imported From .svg Library into project as**

```js
// Imports: Dependencies
import { chromeIcon  } from '@jeff/svgs';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ESNext",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "CommonJS",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["ES2017"],                        /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                          /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "declaration": true,                      /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                       /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "noEmit": false,                          /* Do not emit outputs. */
    "incremental": true,                      /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "isolatedModules": false,                 /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    /* STRICT TYPE-CHECKING OPTIONS */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,              /* Enable strict checking of function types. */

    // MODULE RESOLUTION OPTIONS
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./",                          /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "types": ["jest"],                        /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": false                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "CHANGELOG",
    "README",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js",
    "tsconfig.json",
    "**/**/__tests__/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

**And here's what's in my `.dist`**

- `index.d.ts`
- `index.js`
- `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo`